# Chocolatey: Simple Automatic Upgrades of Local Folder Packages

Tags: upgrade, updates, auto-update, chocolatey

I have a folder like `c:\chocopkg` where I put a couple of packages which I can't find on the official repo.
Creating  nupkg archives was really simple and fun. Instead, the [Automatic Updater (AU)](https://chocolatey.org/docs/automatic-packages#automatic-updater-au) is too much for me: there is no simple `cinst au`; one should clone a git repo and also setup a new one even for a [local run](https://github.com/majkinetor/au/wiki#local-run).

What I need is very simple. I added a script  `<package>\tools\chocolateyBeforeUpgrade.ps1`, with trivial `Invoke-WebRequest` regexps. It checks for new versions on the vendor's site and can update `chocolateyInstall.ps1`.

My first question  is: Is there some config option to have `cup all` running a script like this before checking for package status?

If this is not possible, it would be also simple to wrap  `cup` in a, say, `cup2` checking and running automatic upgrades, but what file should this wrapper edit before giving control to actual `cup`?
[cup](https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-upgrade) page just says it "upgrades a package or a list of packages", but I don't understand how. I can speculate it  looks at the `.nuspec` version. However in a local share there is no such info without unzipping the `.nupkg` file  and  for remote packages  this would require a possibly large download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AU essentially does what you'll need, even if it is a little more setup and work. I know it may feel like too much to start, but you can just start with the files that run the updates.

> What I need is very simple. I added a script  `<package>\tools\chocolateyBeforeUpgrade.ps1`, with trivial `Invoke-WebRequest` regexps. It checks for new versions on the vendor's site and can update `chocolateyInstall.ps1`.

This isn't going to help with upgrades as it is a chicken and egg scenario. You need the updated package first to be able to upgrade a package. So putting something into beforemodify or the install script is only going to help you on installation. BeforeModify only runs from the already installed package on upgrade/uninstall, so unless there